# Override type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to overwrite type in typescript but to allow only properties from the exetended interface :

```
interface A {
  Foo : unknown; 
  Bar : any;
}
```

And I want to write an interface B like this :

```
interface B /** something */ A {
 Foo : string; 
 Bar : number;
 Foobar : string // here I want an error since foobar is not in A
}
```

Thank everyone for any suggestions and any guidance

Comment: There is no error: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIGID2ByAXMgK4gDWIBA7iANzI7IBCcUpycIAnoywBfLFlCRYiFG2QQAHpBAATAM5pMOQsTIqwUUAHNmODlzIhyAWwBG0QfiLXO3XfpAHkAek-IAFtBQwfygUYDVeWSgoAi4VUCRkGEdnMORaMGRQNGEsIA) Also `interface` is lowercase.

Comment: I know but I want an error

Comment: Are you sure? Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - I don't see a reason to try and change the `extend` semantics. If you only want two properties, and to determine the types of those, you can use a generic. Without needing to try and jump through hoops to make `extends` work differently than it does.

Comment: Generic might work but if there is lot of properties it might be confusing that’s why I want something like extended

Comment: If you have *a lot* of properties and you really *absolutely* need to keep redefining them with different types over and over again, I'm not sure the type system would help. That sounds more of a design problem to solve than "throw types at it".

Comment: This is not possible as asked. You can write code that gives you an error *elsewhere*, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyQQZW).  Does that fully address the question? If so, then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve doesn't look very reasonable. To answer you question. *No*, you can't do something like overriding a `type`. However, you could mimic the described behavior using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper type.

In the snippet below I called it `Extend<T, U>` although it doesn't really *extend* anything but only allows you to compute a new type with altered property types based on a given [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html).

```
interface A {
  Foo: unknown;
  Bar: any;
}

type Extend<T, U extends Record<keyof T, any>> = keyof U extends keyof T
  ? U
  : never;

type B = Extend<A, { Foo: string; Bar: number }>;
//   ^? type B = { Foo: string; Bar: number; }
type InvalidB = Extend<A, { Foo: string; Bar: number; Foobar: string }>;
//   ^? type InvalidB = never
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIGID2BAXMgK4gDWIBA7iANw7IBCcUpcIAnkwL5YsYbgAcUAUQAekEABMAPABUANMgCqyCNIhyAzsgBKEBASgLKEbgRjIVyLtwB8j5AF5kFqzY1aZs-Z7WtswA-OrMpCAQAG7QTEKiKCxuyFJ%208qiqGPhEpLpgUKAA5gys7JFkALYARtDIfI5MAPRNuMgAemHCYqwp2YQkyPmFICVlHMggVbVQpQLdKACSINFwADbAssnuaToKmZg5g8PFpWwTUzVxR9XlQwXF9Y1YLW2dyAvIy6sbWylRsSgWCAA)